# cannot access page directly from url jsp/servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have been given a task to troubleshoot this error on this existing web app and I am not familiar with jsp/servlet. When a user logs in, he/she will be able to access all modules but there is one specific module that cannot be accessed directly from the url (when logically it should be able to) but if not directly from url, it can be accessed. It always redirects to the restricted warning.

Any ideas why? I already checked url mapping on web.xml, should have no problem with that. I am guessing that because only this module have this http session in the servlet and jsp file.

```
HttpSession RSession = request.getSession();
if(!"yesdirect".equals(RSession.getAttribute("vdirect"))){

    if(!"yesdirect".equals(request.getParameter("vdirect"))){
        response.sendRedirect("PermissionRestricted.jsp");
    }       
    else{
        RSession.setAttribute("vdirect", "yesdirect");  
    }
}
```

Any ideas or insight would be appreciated. Probably something is wrong in the codes or anything?

Thank you.

Comment: well I guess that the parameter `vdirect` is not set.  What happens when you call it directly from a browser with the parameter set?

Comment: u mean if the parameter "vdirect" is called directly?

Comment: I mean http://nameofyouserver/nameofyouapp/nameofyourservlet?vdirect=some_stuff

Comment: Oh sorry. Shows how inexperienced I am. When called directly using parameter set, also redirects it to the restricted warning. I forgot to mention that this would happen when user first login to the web. If the user has click on other module before accessing the troubled module, it can be accessed by the url.

Comment: I suspect this needs a parameter set in the session as well as on the query string.

Comment: Ah, finally some replies. But this web is going to be scrapped (client needs a lot of changes to be done anyway, hence will build new web app), still I would try do set the parameter. Will try when I am free. Thank you for pointing out this possibility, Evan.

Answer (score -1):

please change the code with using toString()

```
HttpSession RSession = request.getSession();
if (!"yesdirect".equals(RSession.getAttribute("vdirect").toString())) {

    if (!"yesdirect".equals(request.getParameter("vdirect").toString())) {
        response.sendRedirect("PermissionRestricted.jsp");
    } else {
        RSession.setAttribute("vdirect", "yesdirect");
    }
}
```

Comment: If the original variable set on the session was a String, this will not be necessary. If the original variable was not a String, this equality check will always fail. So I don't think `toString()` is going to help.

Comment: I'm expecting you will get a null pointer exception now  if vdirect is not in session